# SQLite on BlackBerry giving SQL logic error or missing database error

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, blackberry

Hey all, I have the following problem. I recently added an extra column to my database in SQLite and now it's giving me a `SQL logic error or missing database error` I made the change to the database and deleted the virtual SD card on the BB simulator to delete the old database and allow the new one to be created on the simulator, the code of the function giving the problem is the following:

```
public Vector obtenerVoiceNotes() 
{
    Vector voiceNotes = new Vector();

    long id, idRemoto, duracion;
    byte[] audioArray;
    String nombre, comentario;

    try
    {
        // Se prepara la sentencia SQL
        Statement statement = _BD.createStatement("SELECT * FROM VoiceNote WHERE idUsuario = ?");
        statement.prepare();

        statement.bind(1, MainApp._user.getIdUser());

        // Se define un cursor para navegar por el resultado
        Cursor cursor = statement.getCursor();

        // Se itera sobre el cursor y se agrega al arreglo de notas 
        while(cursor.next())
        {
            Row row = cursor.getRow();

            id = row.getInteger(0);
            audioArray = row.getBlobBytes(1);
            nombre = row.getString(2);
            comentario = row.getString(3);
            idRemoto = row.getInteger(4);
            duracion = row.getInteger(5);

            long userId = MainApp._user.getIdUser();

            VoiceNote voiceNote = new VoiceNote(nombre, comentario, audioArray, userId);
            voiceNote.set_id(id);
            voiceNote.set_idRemoto(idRemoto);
            voiceNote.set_duration(duracion);

            voiceNotes.addElement(voiceNote);
        }

    }
    catch (DatabaseException e)
    {
        System.out.println();
        MainApp.messageDialog(e.toString());
    } catch (DataTypeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        MainApp.messageDialog(e.toString());
    }

    // Se retorna el arreglo de notas obtenido
    return voiceNotes;
}
```

The exception happens on `statement.prepare()` this is the create statement for my table:

```
CREATE TABLE "VoiceNote" (
    "ID"         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
    "Track"      BLOB,
    "Nombre"     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Comentario" VARCHAR(80),
    "idRemoto"   INTEGER     NOT NULL  DEFAULT -1,
    "Duracion"   INTEGER     NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0,
    "idUsuario"  INTEGER      NOT NULL  DEFAULT -1)
```

The new column is `idUsuario` if i revert the change there no longer is any problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the database had been changed but not committed - meaning that the next query to the database would return a 'corrupted' state.

Be sure to commit any changes - and make sure extreme changes like this if done on the fly are carried out on a locked database (don't want any other pesky threads trying to access it!)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solved this. I deleted the application from the simulator along with the SD card. I dumped and recreated the database to ensure I have the correct logic on the phone and it worked fine.